# How to ignore files with a specific name using read.csv

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I currently have this code to read all the .cvs files in a directory:

```
test <- NULL

for (f in dir("/Users/jackdavis/Desktop/Results/", pattern=".csv", recursive=T)) {
  print(f)
  tmp <- read.csv(paste("/Users/jackdavis/Desktop/Results/",f,sep=""))
  test1 <- rbind(test,data.frame(ID=f,
                            Date=tmp$TEST_DATE,
                            Time=tmp$TEST_TIME,
                            Machine=tmp$DEVICE,
                            Op=tmp$OPERATOR,
                            PTC=pcq$SAMPLECODE
  ))
}
```

The files it reads are in this file name format ("FMQ_Results_TB_1051-1080_1633016575.csv"). But I want it to ignore file names with "rerun" in (E.g. "FMQ_Results_TB_1051-1080_rerun_1633016575.csv") - How can I modify the code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
library(stringr)

p <-  dir("/Users/jackdavis/Desktop/Results/", pattern=".csv", recursive=T)
idx <- str_detect(p,"rerun")
p <- p[-idx]

test <- NULL

for (f in p) {
  print(f)
  tmp <- read.csv(paste("/Users/jackdavis/Desktop/Results/",f,sep=""))
  test1 <- rbind(test,data.frame(ID=f,
                            Date=tmp$TEST_DATE,
                            Time=tmp$TEST_TIME,
                            Machine=tmp$DEVICE,
                            Op=tmp$OPERATOR,
                            PTC=pcq$SAMPLECODE
  ))
}
```